# Can I yield to a child process and return the response in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, koa

In short, I've run into an issue where multiple parallel `GET` requests to my Node.js server cause the server to get "clogged up" and hang, thus resulting in timeouts for the clients (503, service unavailable).

After a lot of performance analysis, I've realized it's a CPU issue. The specific request (we'll call it `GET /foo`) queries data from multiple services over HTTP, and then does a lot of computation, and returns the results to the client, like this:

1. Client request `GET /foo`
2. `/foo` controller queries data over HTTP from multiple other services`
3. `/foo` controller then does a bunch of iterations over the data to compile some output for the client

Step 3 takes around 2 seconds to complete. However, if I send 2 requests in parallel to `/foo`, each client will receive their response in about 4 seconds. When I run the app in a cluster using more cores, the requests run much faster, but not quite what I want.

Seems like I have several options here:

1. pre-compute the response (ideally would like to avoid this for now, since it will require a whole "cache invalidation" scheme), or
2. `/foo` sends the CPU-blocking computation asynchronously to another process (using Heroku, so that would be another dyno), and then I can use a websocket or something to push the results to the client (again, very complex for my situation), or
3. somehow yield to a child process in the request and return the results to the client

**Would love to do something like option 3. Something like this:**

```
get('/foo', function*(request) {
  // I/O, so not blocking the event loop (I think)
  let data = yield getData(request)

  // make this happen in a different process
  let response = yield doSomeHeavyProcessing(data)

  return response
})
```

I've omitted a lot of implementation details above, but if it's necessary to know, I'm using [Koa](http://koajs.com/) and Node.js 6.

Ideally, `doSomeHeavyProcessing` would do the CPU-intensive computation in some separate process, and when it's done, still send the results back in a "synchronous" fashion to the request client.

Been trying to wrap my head around child processes, web workers, fibers, etc., and have been doing some basic "hello worlds" with these to get them to do basically the above, but to no avail. Can post more details if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some approaches that you can try:

**1.**
Split blocking computation in small chunks and use `setImmediate` to place the next chunk of work at the end of the event queue. So computation is no longer blocking and other requests can be processed.

**2.**
Microsoft recently released [napajs](https://github.com/Microsoft/napajs). As stated in their README

> As it evolves, we find it useful to complement Node.js in CPU-bound tasks, with the capability of executing JavaScript in multiple V8 isolates and communicating between them.

I haven't tried it, but it looks very promising:

```
var napa = require('napajs');
var zone1 = napa.zone.create('zone1', { workers: 4 });

get('/foo', function*(request) {
  let data = yield getData(request)

  let response = yield zone1.execute(doSomeHeavyProcessing, [data])

  return response
})
```

**3.** If nothing of the above is enough and you need to spread the load across multiple machines, then you probably couldn't avoid using some sort of message queue to distribute work to different servers. In this case check out [ZeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js). It is extremely easy to use from node, and you can implement any kind of distributed messaging pattern with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize [Child process](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/child_process.html) with additional wrapper for convenience.

**worker.js** - this module will run in a separate process and will do the heavy work

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function doHeavyWork(data) {
  return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(data, 'salt', 100000, 64, 'sha512');
}

process.on('message', (message) => {
  const result = doHeavyWork(message.data);
  process.send({ id: message.id, result });
});
```

**client.js** - a convenience (but primitive) wrapper for *Child process*

```
const cp = require('child_process');

let worker;
const resolves = new Map();

module.exports = {
  init(moduleName, errorCallback) {
    worker = cp.fork(moduleName);
    worker.on('error', errorCallback);

    worker.on('message', (message) => {
      const resolve = resolves.get(message.id);
      resolves.delete(message.id);
      if (!resolve) {
        errorCallback(new Error(`Got response from worker with unknown id: ${message.id}`));
        return;
      }

      resolve(message.result);
    });

    console.log(`Service PID: ${process.pid}, Worker PID: ${worker.pid}`);
  },

  doHeavyWorkRemotly(data) {
    const id = `${Date.now()}${Math.random()}`;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      worker.send({ id, data });
      resolves.set(id, resolve);
    });
  }
}
```

I use [`fork()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) to utilize an additional communication channel as it is stated in the docs.

Also I keep a record of all submitted to worker process requests (`const resolves = new Map();`) and resolve Promises (`resolve(message.result);`) only when the worker process returns response for the specific request (`const resolve = resolves.get(message.id);`).

**run.js** - a startup module, it utilizes `co` to 'execute' generators.

```
const co = require('co');

const client = require('./client');

function errorCallback(error) {
  console.log('Got an unexpected error!');
  console.log(error);
}

client.init('./worker.js', errorCallback);

function* run() {
  while(true) {
    yield client.doHeavyWorkRemotly('mydata');
  }
}

co(run);
```

To test it simply run `node run.js`, it will print

> Service PID: XXXX, Worker PID: XXXX

then take a look at CPU utilization, worker process will probably take around 100% of CPU while Service will be quite idle.